# И как результат - обособляется ли?

Tags: пунктуация

Обособляется ли сочетание "как результат"? В каких случаях?
1. "И как результат - напряжение уходит". 2. "Этот стиль подразумевает признание ограничений и как результат - эффективность работы".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как результат, как следствие - вводные слова. В первом предложении вводное слово И тесно примыкает к нему и не обособляется.Во втором предложении вводное слово выделяется запятыми, тире в неполном предложении на месте пропущенного сказуемого.
Похожее предложение из учебника: "В науке особенно сказался ее разболтанный характер и, как следствие, - неумение найти верный путь".